# Where to download replacement "Explorerframe.DLL" Files for x64 Windows 7 Pro?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, dll

**After posting this question, I did some research to reveal what the problem likely was, and found what I need to fix. Following this is the original post, then my updated question.**

*A few months ago I ended up requiring to change my computer's SID to fix a problem it had been having- Instead of fixing the problem, though, it screwed up my at-the-time current install of windows, to the point of me needing to do a fresh install. As I am in possession of an OEM copy of Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit, I successfully reinstalled over the dead copy with that (all the files that were on the computer previous to this windows install were put in a Windows.old folder). Everything installed and worked absolutely fine, except for one thing.
The problem I am experiencing is that, in some Windows Explorer windows, the explorer pane doesn't show. Instead, it simply shows a white area where the pane would show. This makes some software not usable, I recently realized; Software such as Cubase, which use just the explorer pane to select file save locations, cannot save at all as the pane itself is... not operational. Below is a screenshot of this problem as it occurs in cubase;
[image]
...and again as it shows in UTorrent in the save location selector window. The highlighted area is where the sidebar would NORMALLY be.
[image]
Pardon my scribbling over some of the things in the window- I would personally rather the internet did not get a glimpse of my files.
I have yet to find a common reason why the pane works in some applications when they pull explorer, and others not. I have yet to see it go away, and the software affected by it has been affected since I reinstalled my copy of windows.  Initially, I was able to live with it as I can type out save locations in the file name bar to navigate, but with software like Cubase, I do not have this option.
Reinstalling windows again is NOT an option.*

**Here's the updated question.**

After posting this question originally, I did some research on the problem in question, and it turns out that this is extremely easily fixable via replacing the file "ExplorerFrame.DLL" which is located in the System32 and SystemWOW64 Folders, in the windows folder, on the C:\ drive.

As I quite frequently customize my computer, this is a normal thing for me to do and I know exactly how to safely and properly replace this file. The only problem is that I cannot for the life of me find a download of this file that actually works with my computer. I tried a couple from some different sites but they all caused explorer to not restart (I was given an error when starting the application from Task Manager) and was forced to revert to the broken .DLL files.

Since there are 2 separate "ExplorerFrame.DLL" files; one for 64 bit and the other for 32 bit, I am assuming that I will need to download 2 separate versions to replace the corrupted ones.

Where can I acquire these files?

*I am currently running Windows 7 Professional x64 Bit.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a backup of a previous windows install I preformed of the exact same version, and copied the files from that onto my current install. I reloaded explorer and it worked *flawlessly.*

I was able to start Cubase and get right into my projects and start working again. Yay! :D